# Error in imputing daily time series with zoo package

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

The `na.StructTS()`-function, according to it's documentation, is for filling `NA`values in time series using seasonal Kalman Filter (not familiar with the mathematics behind this one).

But I have a problem:

When I want to replace `NA`s in a `zooreg` object, it only works if the specified frequency (observation per time unit) is greater than 1.

Example:

```
#with frequency = 1 appearantly being the default
t <- zooreg(c(34, 12, 45, 56, 34, NA, 57, 59), 
            start = as.Date("2019-01-01"))

> t
2019-01-01 2019-01-02 2019-01-03 2019-01-04 2019-01-05 2019-01-06 2019-01-07 2019-01-08 
        34         12         45         56         34         NA         57         59 

na.StructTS(t, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Returns the error:

> Error in rowSums(tsSmooth(StructTS(y))[, -2]) : 
>     'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Changing:

```
t <- zooreg(c(34, 12, 45, 56, 34, NA, 57, 59), 
            start = as.Date("2019-01-01"), frequency = 2)

> na.StructTS(t, na.rm = TRUE)
2019-01-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-02 2019-01-02 2019-01-03 2019-01-03 2019-01-04 2019-01-04 
  34.00000   12.00000   45.00000   56.00000   34.00000   49.84633   57.00000   59.00000
```

to anything `> 1` works, but the imputations are different each time, and take increasingly long.

Why is that behaviour? How can I impute a daily time series with `na.StructTS()`?

Comment: It really makes no sense to talk about seasonal series when you only have one season or less which is what you seem to want.

Comment: This is just a very simple example. With or without seasonality it works with `frequency > 1`  and doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: It does work.  It's what you are asking for that doesn't make sense.  Realize that a complete cycle must equal 1 so if there are 4 seasons, say, then we must have, for example, times of 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 for  complete cycle.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it.. Do you have a link where I can read about that?

Comment: I am not sure if this is well explained in any official source but a complete cycle must be represented by a unit of time, i.e. 1, and  if there are n periods in a cycle then their times must be represented by offsets of 0, 1/n, ..., (n-1)/n so if you represent time that way then `ts` and related functions based on it will work.  For example, 2000, 2000.25, 2000.5, 2000.75 could represent the 4 quarters of year 2000.  If you represent time in some other fashion functions which are based on ts won't work propertly.  Maybe someone else knows of a good link for this.

Comment: Here lies the problem: rowSums(tsSmooth(StructTS(y))[, -2]) - If frequency > 1, tsSmooth gives as output 'level', 'slope', 'sea'. From which 'slope' is dropped and the rowSum is calculated. If the frequency is 1, tsSmooth only gives 'level' and 'slope' as output - still the second variable is dropped. Then rowSum fails, because it needs at least 2 variables. Easy solution to fix in the package would be to just use rowSums(tsSmooth(StructTS(y))) - I anyway did not understand why to drop 'slope'.

Comment: You can test this by using the series 't' from above : tsSmooth(StructTS( t ))

Comment: Exactly, that's what I have also observed when comparing `zooreg`s with `frequency = 1` and `frequency > 1`. My question thus is the same: Why make it fail when `frequency = 1`? G. Grothendieck probably tried to explain the rationale, but I failed to grasp it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would be interesting to know, what kind of series you have in mind.
`na.Struct()` might not be the best choice for very short series.

There are a lot of other imputation methods (some easier to understand).
E.g. **`zoo`** also offers `na.approx` , `na.spline` , `na.StructTS` , `na.locf`

There is also the **`imputeTS`** package, which is solely about time series imputation. (and should also be compatible with `zoo` time series, so you can just use it on zoo series)

In imputeTS package you have: `na_interpolation()`, `na_locf()`, `na_ma()`, `na_kalman()`, `na_seadec()`, `na_seasplit()` and even more [functions](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-009/index.html).

If you want to stay with Kalman filter maybe look at the `na_kalman()` function

> na_kalman(x, model = "StructTS", smooth = TRUE, nit = -1, ...)

It has several additional options, so you could use a ARIMA model instead of the one from StructTS or you can choose if you want to use KalmanRun or KalmanSmoothing.

```
na_kalman(x, model = "StructTS", smooth = TRUE)
```

would be most similar to
na.StructTS. But still different implementations - so they won't give exactly the same results. So if you insist on KalmanSmoothing on State Space Models, you can go with this function from imputeTS (does not give an error for frequency = 1)